# Different size pointer cast warning in ARM64 system

Tags: c, gcc, linker, arm, arm64

I run a baremetal Xilinx-based ARM A57 system.

I want to bring the addresses of two linker-defined symbols to my c program...

This is the linker script:

```
.mutex_ram: {
     _mutex_start = .;
     . += _MUTEX_SIZE;
     . = ALIGN(8);
     _mutex_end = .;
} > mem_common
```

This is a brief summary of what I want to do in C.

```
extern int _mutex_start;
extern int _mutex_end;
void some_fcn(void) 
{
    int size = (int)(&_mutex_end)-(int)(&_mutex_start);
    memset(&_mutex_start,0,size);
}
```

Why the heck does the compiler warn me that this is a different-size integer cast? I just don't get it...

```
warning: cast from pointer to integer of different size [-Wpointer-to-int-cast]
```

Can somebody help me?

Comment: `int size` -> `size_t size`. On your platform `int` is probably 32 bit whereas the size of a pointer is 64 bit.

Comment: Actually it should be `size_t size = (size_t)(&_mutex_end - &_mutex_start)`

Comment: @Jabberwocky The integer types that have size of pointers are `intptr_t` and `uintptr_t`. But In this case casting the difference (`ptrdiff_t`) to `size_t` looks reasonable.

Comment: @MikeCAT good point, but how would you write this?

Comment: size_t size didn't do the trick :(

Comment: @hendrikschnack did you do what I suggested in my _second_ comment? It works here: https://www.godbolt.org/z/MjG5rf

Comment: @Jabberwocky (&_mutex_end - &_mutex_start) is not legal according to MISRA C as you cannot subtract pointers from different objects

Comment: @hendrikschnack then you need `ptrdiff_t size = (ptrdiff_t)((intptr_t)&_mutex_end -  (intptr_t)&_mutex_start);`. You may need to include `<stdint.h>`

Comment: @Jabberwocky: yeah man, you are a genius. Just checked your solution against my MISRA pipeline and it passed...

Comment: @hendrikschnack BTW `(&_mutex_end - &_mutex_start)` was wrong anyway, not only in terms of MISRA, because as per pointer arithmetic the result was divided by the `sizeof(int)`.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Jabberwocky, I used

```
ptrdiff_t size = (ptrdiff_t)((intptr_t)&_mutex_end -  (intptr_t)&_mutex_start);
```

I wasn't aware that using ptr_diff_t is actually MISRA-compliant... Thanks for the help!